# How to get results when use Task.WhenAll

Tags: c#, async-await, task, task-parallel-library

Let's suppose I have a web service that adds an account. I should use this service to add a list of accounts:

```
"40701", "40702", "40703", "40704", "40705"
```

I tried to simulate not stable working of this service for testing purposes and particularly the situation where at the first attempt the first three accounts are added, the other two accounts go to the second round. At the second attempt only "40704" account are added, the "40705" account goes to the third round and at the third attemp it is added.

```
public class AddingAccounts
{
    int triesCount = 0;

    // decision table to add accounts
    readonly int[][] dt =
    {
        new int[] { 1, 2, 3 },
        new int[] { 4 },
        new int[] { 5 }
    };

    List<int> result = new List<int>();

    public async Task<List<string>> GetAccountsAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1500);
        return new List<string> { "40701", "40702", "40703", "40704", "40705" };
    }

    public async Task<int> AddAccount(string account)
    {
        try
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);

            // define accounts at the current attempt
            var accountsToAdd = dt[triesCount].Select(x => $"4070{x}");

            if (accountsToAdd.Contains(account))
            {
                // simulate successful operation, return id account
                return new Random().Next(100);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Account {account} was not added");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.Data["account"] = account; 
            throw;
        }
    }

    public async Task<List<int>> AddAccountsAsync(List<string> accounts)
    {
        var tasks = accounts.Select(ac => AddAccount(ac));
        Task<int[]> allTasks = Task.WhenAll(tasks);

        try
        {
            var res = await allTasks; 
            result.AddRange(res);  
        }
        catch
        {
            // how can I add returned values of successfully completed tasks to result variable here ?
            // I tried to use tasks variable as John advised
            foreach (var t in tasks)
            {
                // but most tasks have WaitingForActivation status and Result of 0
                if (t.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
                {
                    result.Add(t.Result);
                }
            }

            List<string> failedToAddAccounts = new List<string>();

            AggregateException ae = allTasks.Exception;
            foreach(var ex in ae.Flatten().InnerExceptions)
            {                   
                if (ex.Data["account"] is string failedAccount)
                {
                    failedToAddAccounts.Add(failedAccount);
                }
            }

            triesCount++;
            return await AddAccountsAsync(failedToAddAccounts);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

I want to get all five accounts id.

How can I get the result of successfully completed tasks in `try/catch` block? I mean on the first round when I await `allTasks`, `allTasks` has the `Faulted` status and I can't get the return values for the first added accounts.

Comment: You already have the original tasks in `tasks`. All of those will have completed (whether successfully or not) by the time `allTasks` has completed, so use those tasks.

Comment: Why do you have `new Random().Next(100)`? You know that this is quite likely to result in duplicate numbers that aren't random? `new Random()` should always be created once per thread to avoid this bug.

Comment: With this line of code I just return some id. As I said I simulate web service method that adds an account and returns its id. So, actually, it's not so important whether they are unique or not. Anyway, thanks for your comment, I didn't know about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider Microsoft's Reactive Framework (Rx) for this. It's much easier and more powerful than using tasks.

First up I rewrote your test code for a bit more simplicity:

```
public async Task<List<string>> GetAccountsAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(1500);
    return new List<string> { "40701", "40702", "40703", "40704", "40705" };
}

private Random _rnd = new Random();

public async Task<int> AddAccount(string account)
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);

    if (_rnd.NextDouble() > 0.5)
    {
        return _rnd.Next(100);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("!");
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"Account {account} was not added");
    }
}
```

Now, using Rx for this is a breeze:

```
var query =
    from accounts in Observable.FromAsync(() => GetAccountsAsync())
    from account in accounts.ToObservable()
    from id in Observable.Defer(() => Observable.FromAsync(() => AddAccount(account))).Retry(3)
    select new { account, id };
```

It's lazily evaluated like LINQ, so to execute it you do this:

```
IDisposable subscription =
    query
        .Subscribe(
            result => Console.WriteLine($"Account {result.account} created with id {result.id}"),
            ex => Console.WriteLine($"Exception {ex.GetType().FullName} with \"{ex.Message}\"."),
            () => Console.WriteLine("Completed Successfully"));
```

To cancel execution before it completes naturally just call `subscription.Dispose()`.

Here are a couple of sample runs:

**With Error**

```
Account 40705 created with id 63
throwing on 40704!
Account 40701 created with id 21
Account 40702 created with id 21
Account 40703 created with id 27
throwing on 40704!
throwing on 40704!
Exception System.InvalidOperationException with "Account 40704 was not added".
```

**Completed Successfully**

```
throwing on 40703!
throwing on 40702!
Account 40701 created with id 25
Account 40704 created with id 88
Account 40705 created with id 26
Account 40703 created with id 43
Account 40702 created with id 98
Completed Successfully
```

Note that there were some errors, but the `.Retry(3)` operator simply retried creating the account and was eventually successful.

Just NuGet "System.Reactive" and use the namespace `System.Reactive.Linq` to get this to work.

Comment: Wow! That's very cool! And how can I get a list of id of added accounts?

Comment: @DmitryStepanov - The query is already returning the ids one at a time. If you want them all at once you can put a `.ToArray()` at the end of the query then you'll get all the results when the query ends.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You answer has encouraged me to start learning Rx.

Comment: @DmitryStepanov - It's incredibly powerful. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Actually, I have a couple of questions: 1) Is it possible to add delay in ms between retries? 2) Is it possible to add an action if retry fails (I want to log it) ? Thanks in advance

Comment: @DmitryStepanov - Have a look at `Observable.Delay` and `Observable.Catch` they might help.